# The save appscript function doesn't work in google sheet

Tags: sourceforge-appscript

I have created a user form in Google Sheets using Appscript and it has been working for a few weeks but suddenly the save function is not working. Please help me

save function. So that the data input on the Google form is captured automatically on the data recap sheet on the Google sheet. But this function suddenly doesn't work after it was just normal before